# how to add navigation bar UISearchBar

Tags: objective-c, ipad

//  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:
//                                             UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd  target:self action:@selector(addWord)] autorelease];

with this i can add button to rightside to the naivation bar.

How to add UISearchBar in middle to the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want the `UISearchBar` on the navigation bar. Normally the implementation is just below the Navigation bar, and you can set it as your `tableHeaderView`

But for adding the Searchbar to your navigation bar, you cannot add the `UISearchBar` directly. You can add the Navigation Bar, and your UISearchBar as subviews to a view (lets say `comboView`) and then add it to your `self.view` or your `tableHeaderView`.

```
UIView * comboView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45)];
[comboView addSubview:navigationBar];
[comboView addSubview:searchBar];

// You should have allocated the navigation bar and the search bar before this though.

self.tableView.tableHeaderView= comboView;
```